# change the legth of time the "Success! Case Created" notification shows

Tags: service-cloud-console, feed-based-layout

We're using the contact feed layout for our customer service reps.  When they create a case on the contact feed layout page there's a quick note at the bottom of the feed that says, "Success! Case Created".  Anyone know how to make this notification stay on the screen longer?

[image]